# Watir Scraping Rails - Set date of input that exists? but is not present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, web-scraping, watir

Good morning everybody,

I have been trying to scrape this page: https://www.aftnet.be/MyAFT/Competitions/Tournaments but I have run into some problems.

[Collapsed Search Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyZtX.png)

[Search Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlHSt.png)

If you click  *> Recherche détaillée* , a search form appears along with the OK button to run it. The markup of the page is not that great but with the following I manage to run the search with no specific search criterion set:

```
browser.button(text: 'OK').fire_event "onclick"
```

However for my current use I would need to be able to specify the date range:

```
browser.input(id: 'periodStartDate').exists? --> TRUE
browser.input(id: 'periodEndDate').exists? --> TRUE
browser.input(id: 'periodStartDate').present? --> FALSE
browser.input(id: 'periodEndDate').present? --> FALSE
```

I have tried setting the value of those using `browser.input(id: 'periodStartDate').value ='03/06/2021'` but to no avail.

I also tried  : `browser.text_field(id: 'periodStartDate').set('03/06/2021')` but that also did not work.

I have come to wonder whether it was because it was not possible to set a value of an element that exists but is not present so I tried to click  *> Recherche détaillée*  with Watir to collapse the search form and then have the search fields present. But I also haven't managed to make it work using : `browser.link(text: 'Recherche détaillée').click`

What I truly do not understand is that:

```
browser.link(text: 'Recherche détaillée').exists? --> TRUE
browser.link(text: 'Recherche détaillée').present? --> FALSE
```

Watir basically seems to not see that anchor present when it is visible when opening the page by default.

At this stage I don't know what else to try and that's why I'm here hoping someone can help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you expand the collapsed section before trying to interact with the date field? `#exists?` tells you the element is on the page. `#present?` tells you if the user can see/interact with the element. If the section is still collapsed, the user cannot see/interact with it.

Comment: That's what I understood from trying several things but I also wasn't able to expand the collapsed section I'm afraid. Any help to do so, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well I've solved it. In case anyone struggles with something similar, the reason why even some elements that I did see on my browser when opening the page were not visible on Watir, was because Watir opened the webpage with a window size that was small enough to trigger the mobile version. 

So resizing the window to view the desktop version made it all work.

 Conclusion, when something does not quite match what you see, `browser.driver.save_screenshot` is the way!